# FacebookSDK for iOS, Facebook login doesn't Get back to my iOS app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook

I am trying to use the Facebook sdk with my iOS application,

1. I am using xcode 4.5.2 with SDK v6.0
2. My device is iPod touch v6.0.1
3. I have a provisioning profile set
4. I have subscribed as a facebook developer and registered a facebook app inclusing

   - 'Bundle ID'
   - 'Enabling 'Facebook Login'.
   - ...
5. I have set the facebook AppId at my plist file under 'URL Types'->'Item 0'->'URL 
   Scemes'->'Item 0'.

When using the physical device, my application is switching to the facebook login page, however, after logging in, it **doesn't go back** to my application!!!
**Surprisingly**, when using the simulator everything works great, my app is going back and forth from the facebook login page.

What might I be doing wrong? why on the physical device I cannot get back to my app after logging in while when using the Simulator I can? might this be somehow related with the provisioning profile ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At earl year, i got a same issue and i am testing with `HACKBOOK` example and as same as your issue. i can run well in simulator but when i tested in device i got same problum and then i just put that bellow code and working great.

simply you just need to add this method in your app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [self.facebook handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

This method usefull for login with fbApp or safari. for redirect back to our app from facebook login page

Comment: I have this part in my application, IMO, if this was omitted, the Simulator app wouldn't have switched back from the login page, the problem is that while with the simulator, the app is switched back from the safari login page, and, when executed on the physical device it does not!

Answer (score 0):

Go to facebook.m class in your SDK find this method:

```
- (void)authorize:(NSArray *)permissions
         delegate:(id<FBSessionDelegate>)delegate
```

Then replace your last line which is:`[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:YES safariAuth:YES];`

With this line:`[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:YES safariAuth:NO;`& check.

Comment: I am assuming you are suggesting me to modify the Facebook SDK code ( taking from github ), isn't there a more elegant solution for the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the base class was implementing 'applicationDidBecomeActive' and 'applicationWillTerminate' ( where '[FBSession.activeSession handleDidBecomeActive]' and  '[self.session close]' are correspondingly called ) while the inheriting class implemented the same methods w/o calling the base [super] class implementation.